# Parsing Website (XML) for specific with Python and save to mysql

Tags: python, mysql, xml, parsing, screen-scraping

I want to send a REST request to the Flickr API. The response looks like this (XML):

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The 
document tree is shown below.

<rsp stat="ok">
<photos page="1" pages="974001" perpage="250" total="243500161">

<photo id="123" owner="1234" secret="123" server="1" farm="4" 
title="DSC01316" ispublic="1" isfriend="0" isfamily="0" views="0" tags="" 
latitude="47.825188" longitude="11.300722" accuracy="16" context="0" 
place_id="XT" woeid="123" geo_is_family="0" geo_is_friend="0" 
geo_is_contact="0" geo_is_public="1">
<description/>
</photo>

<photo id="123" owner="123" secret="123" server="1" farm="3" 
title="DSC01351" ispublic="1" isfriend="0" isfamily="0" views="0" tags="" 
latitude="47.825263" longitude="11.300891" accuracy="16" context="0" 
place_id="XT" woeid="123" geo_is_family="0" geo_is_friend="0" 
geo_is_contact="0" geo_is_public="1">
<description/>
</photo>

and so forth...
```

What I want python to do is parsing the website for the words photo ID, Owner, Title
etc. and extract the information and save it into a mysql database (set that already up with phpadmin).

For better understanding: I have this table where the first row is my classification and the second row is the extracted data from the example.

```
Photo ID    Owner    Secret    Server    Farm    Title    ispublic    isfriend    isfamily    ....
123         1234     123       1         4       DSC01316 1           0           0
```

I started off with that to extract the information. It does not work though...

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import requests

url="https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=5...b&per_page=250&accuracy=1&has_geo=1&extras=geo,tags,views,description%22"
page=requests.get(url)
data = page.text
root = ET.fromstring(data)
for x in root.Element.get('photo'):
    test = x.get('Photo ID', 'Owner', 'Secret' , 'Server' , 'Farm' , 'Title' , 'ispublic' , 'isfriend' , 'isfamily')
print (test)

#does not work. it says: AttributeError: 'Element' object has no attribute 'Element'
```

Any ideas? 
I am just looking for a hint, I want to write it myself! Note that I am relatively new to python and a link to a documentation site wont work for me. i have too less knowledge for that. I will need a little further explanation.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BeautifulSoup4 makes you easier to parse xml / http documents. Try below code after installing package via `pip install beautifulsoup4`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml = "..."
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml)

for photo in soup.find_all('photo'):
    print(photo.attrs['title'])
```

Then you'll get,

```
DSC01316
DSC01351
```

Check out http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ for more information.

Comment: I thought bs is just for html, not for xml? 
trying your code gives me a `invalid syntax` error and highlights the `photo.attrs`, precisely `photo`. I am pretty sure I had this problem a couple of times already...

Comment: And bs4 describes itself, 'Beautiful Soup is a Python library for pulling data out of HTML and XML files.' :)

Comment: Right, I should have known that. Trying to call this url gives me an error message: I update my post with it.

Comment: Oh hang on. I know why that error message is coming up. I solve it and try it again